# Is there any fastest way to execute For loops in python?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

Is there any fastest way to execute following python code:

```
     L1 = [1,1,1,1,0,0]     
     L2 = [0,0,1,1,0,1]  

     D1 = [0.03,0.04,0.01,0.02,0.01,0.02]    
     D2 = [0.05,0.01,0.03,0.07,0.12,0.41]    
     a = 0
     b = 0        

     for l1,l2,d1,d2 in zip(L1,L2,D1,D2):

            if l1 == 1:      
                a += d1        
            if l2 == 1:    
                b += d2
```

L1,L2,D1 and D2 are of same length and of having near about 4000 entries.

Thanks!

Comment: You may get a performance increase by using `itertools.izip` rather than `zip`.

Comment: Well, you don't need to calculate `a` and `b` each time, for a start...

Comment: Are `L1`, `L2`,`D1`, and `D2` somehow dependent on `i`?  I don't understand what the first loop is even for, as I see no dependence on `i`.  As written, you can just find `a` and `b` then write `A = [a]*40000` and the same for `B`

Comment: @askewchan I'll go further and say I don't have a clue what the OP is trying to achieve at all.... user2766019 - don't worry about what is fast as I suspect the code above isn't even doing what you think it might be to begin with... Perhaps if you explained what you're trying to do, with some simple input and example output - you may even answer your own question

Comment: The outer loop is probably just to run the inner loop 40k times.

Comment: Shouldn't this be moved to the code review stackexchange?

Comment: @askewchan: yes, L1 and L2 is dependant on i, everytime L1 and L2 changes as i contain different values. Just to say that my outer loop runs 40000 times I use i in range(40000)

Comment: @JonClements: My outer loop is just to say that inner loop run 40000 times. My code works fine, jst the inner loop is taking much time to execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If speed is really important and you have large of numerical lists like this, you can use numpy, it would be very helpful here:

```
L1 = np.array([1,1,1,1,0,0])
L2 = np.array([0,0,1,1,0,1])

D1 = np.array([0.03,0.04,0.01,0.02,0.01,0.02])
D2 = np.array([0.05,0.01,0.03,0.07,0.12,0.41])
```

The fastest way is using the vector dot product:

```
a = np.dot(D, L)
```

Other ways include, the sum of values in `D1` where values in `L1` evaluate to `True`:

```
a = D1[L1.astype(bool)].sum()  
b = D2[L2.astype(bool)].sum()
```

Or take the sum of the product of `D1` times `L1`:

```
a = np.sum(D1*L1)
b = np.sum(D2*L2)
```

For timing:

```
L = np.random.random_integers(0,1,4000)
D = np.random.rand(4000)

In [60]: timeit np.dot(D,L)
100000 loops, best of 3: 13.1 µs per loop

In [61]: timeit np.sum(D*L)
10000 loops, best of 3: 33.7 µs per loop

In [62]: timeit D[L.astype(bool)].sum()
10000 loops, best of 3: 65 µs per loop

In [67]: %%timeit
   ....: a = 0
   ....: for l, d in zip(L, D):
   ....:     if l == 1:
   ....:         a += d
   ....: 
100 loops, best of 3: 7.68 ms per loop
```

Comment: @user2766019 I found a faster way!  Please see my edit :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `itertools.compress`:

```
import itertools
a = sum( itertools.compress(D1, L1) )
b = sum( itertools.compress(D2, L2) )
```

`compress` returns an iterator consisting of those elements of the first argument where the corresponding element of the second argument is `True`.

Comment: This is three times faster than OP's loop, and `sum(d for l,d in zip(L,D) if l==1)`, probably the best with standard library.